# Standardizing the number of words by the length of the article for sentiment analysis

Tags: r, syntax-error, standardized

I'm conducting sentiment analysis with a dictionary. The data is newspaper articles, so my unit of analysis needs to be the story and not the sentence (my prof corrected me on this). He also said I needed to standardize the number of words by the length of the article before doing my regression analysis. This is the part I'm struggling with.

```
#clean the data a bit and tokenize
data.C <- read.csv("filelocation",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data.C <- data.frame(data.C)
data.C <- data.C %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)

data.C <- data.C %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by= "word")

# obtain sentiment scores

struggle <- data.frame(data.C) %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn"))

struggle %>%
  group_by(story_index) %>%
  summarize(weights(sum(value)/n()))
```

This last command gets me the error message:

Error in `summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = weights(sum(value)/n())`.
i The error occurred in group 1: story_index = 1.
Caused by error:
! $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

**Also, here's what my data set looks like. The third variable is the sentiment score.
[Snapshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PdoQ.png)

Comment: Please, don't paste picture of your data. Read this on how to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And read the book [Text Mining with R](http://tidytextmining.com/index.html) by the authors of the tidytext package. Chapter 3 should be of help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.